# Безопасность статического сайта

Tags: безопасность

Имеется статический сайт на GitHub Pages, где допустимо хранить только html, css и javascript . [Читал](http://www.thejethost.com/hosting/bezopasnost_sayta.html), что статические сайты [менее](http://forum.e-proficom.ru/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=1702) [уязвимы](http://dizems.ru/v-chem-otlichie-staticheskix-sajtov-ot-dinamicheskix) к взлому, но [не на 100%](http://forum.vingrad.ru/index.php?showtopic=247423&view=findpost&p=1784943).

Пароли хранятся [в надёжном месте](http://pro444.ru/azbuka/scarabay.html), браузер портативный.

Каким образом могут осуществляться хакерские атаки на статический сайт, и как от них защититься?

Comment: Вопрос задан про Github, но ответ, пусть и даденый на примере Github'а, применим для **любого** статического сайта на стороннем хостинге. Заметьте, я не удалял упоминания о Github'е из тела вопроса, только из заголовка и меток. Это делается для того, чтобы все вопросы на данную тему можно было объявлять копиями вашего, что, принесёт пользу как в целом сообществу (не надо давать два десятка однотипных ответов, в которых различаются только названия доменов и хостингов), так и лично вам (больше переходов на вопрос, больше оценок, больше репутации). Про удаление "воды" ответил ранее.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Прежде чем говорить о возможности взлома, надо оценить возможный профит от этого:

- **Получение контроля над чужими вычислительными мощностями**: малореально, Github защищается **даже от вас** в этом отношении: он не позволяет использовать пользовательские плагины для Jekyll (единственного поддерживаемого движка), которые могут содержать произвольный код на Ruby.

  Держитесь крепче за свой GitHub-аккаунт:

  - Включите двухфакторную аутентификацию.
  - Для аутентификации через Git используйте SSH-ключи, и назначайте им такие имена, чтобы можно было узнать, какому ключу при случае закрывать доступ.
- **Получение конфиденциальных данных пользователей**: а вы их собираете? Храните? Github Pages не даёт никаких возможностей по хранению на стороне сервера. Остаётся вариант хранения данных на клиенте (там чего только нет нынче: WebSQL, IndexedDB, LocalStorage) или перехват прямо при вводе.

  При отсутствии доступа к клиенту хотя бы на уровне браузера (если у пользователя вредоносные расширения в браузере или дыры/лазейки в ОС, вы вряд ли что-то сделаете) остаётся только обманом заставить пользователя выполнить JS-код злоумышленника: это **XSS**.

  Самый банальный случай — вывод фрагмента URL без экранирования: если там "случайно" (по присланной кем-то ссылке) окажется `<script>` с вредоносным кодом, браузер его загрузит и выполнит. Бывают и менее явные, [это обширная тема](http://excess-xss.com/).
- **Приведение сайта в неработоспособное состояние**...

  *Блокировки провайдерами* взломом, наверное, всё же не считаются, хотя и делают сайт неработоспособным для определённого круга пользователей. Рассматриваем неработоспособность для всех (или почти всех; конечно, из исходников любой может поднять копию у себя).

  Уязвимым местом является разве что **домен**: его теоретически могут *"угнать"* и направить его к машине злоумышленника. Если вы используете `*.github.io`, то вы полагаетесь в защите домена на GitHub. Если используете собственный, держитесь крепче за аккаунт у регистратора.

Comment: `Jekyll (единственного поддерживаемого движка)` — Вы [**это**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35007980#35007980) примерно имели в виду? Т. е. в репозитории может находиться только код на Ruby без HTML, в который он компилируется? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных ну, исходники сайта, да. Не на Ruby, гитхаб предоставляет [свой набор плагинов](https://pages.github.com/versions/) и не позволяет его менять. HTML+Liquid (шаблоны, вставки, страницы), Markdown/Textile/Asciidoc/и т. д., (посты/страницы) стили на Sass/SCSS, CoffeeScript и любые файлы не требующие предобработки.

Comment: D-Side, да, только хотел поправиться, слишком некорректно выразился. Не «код на Ruby», а исходники сайта, которых достаточно в репозитории для того, чтобы сайт работал, и без HTML, получающегося при сборке. В отличие от других генераторов сайтов, используя которые в репозиторий следует выкладывать как раз содержимое output. Теперь верно выразился?

Comment: @СашаЧерных верно, да.